# Vuex doesn't work as expected - problem with import?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Trying to use Vuex states in components.
This works fine:
`main.js`:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 1
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.counter++
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

and inside component:
`<span>{{this.$store.state.test}}</span>`

---

When I tried to move Vuex to a separate `store.js`, it doesn't work.
`store.js` (right near `main.js`):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 1
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.counter++
    }
  }
})
```

and inside component I make import:
`import store from '../store'`,
than try to use:
`<span>{{store.state.test}}</span>`
and I get

> Property or method "store" is not defined on the instance

`<span>{{this.$store.state.test}}</span>` results

> Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined

I've tried to change `export default new Vuex.Store({...})` to `export const store =  new Vuex.Store({...})` but it didn't helped.

---

P. S. This works for me:
inside component:

```
computed: {
      counter() {
        return store.state.counter
      }
    }
```

and `<span>{{counter}}</span>`.
But is there other way without using `computed` properties? Because I use Vuex for calling its states globally, and here I have to define `computed` in each component anywhere...

Comment: for your second use case, you didn't bind store instance to Vue instance, so it will not work like `<span>{{store.state.test}}</span>`, which is like `this.store.state.test`, but `this.store` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went this way:
`store.js`:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({...})
```

`main.js`:

```
import store from './store'

new Vue({
  ...
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Than in any component's template: `<span>{{this.$store.state.counter}}</span>`.

Can't confirm this is the best way, but it works for me.

Comment: Okay, if that's how it works for you then it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

your export and import don't follow the ES6 rules, 
if you are using `export const store =  new Vuex.Store({...})`
you need to either import like this

```
import {store} from '../store.js'
```

if not, update your code to this:

```
import Vue from 'vue' import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default const store = new Vuex.Store({   state: {
    counter: 1   },   mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.counter++
    }   } })
```

Comment: Seems like wrong syntax with `export default const store = new Vuex.Store({...})`, at least it doesn't compiles...

Comment: I went `export const store =  new Vuex.Store({...})` and `import {store} from '../store.js'`, but still can't access `store` inside component template